# Is it OK to implement a protocol that's unavailable in my deployed OS version?

Tags: objective-c

Say I'm writing an app to run on iOS7 and iOS6. I've a class that implements a protocol - a protocol only available in iOS7 (in this case, NSLayoutManagerDelegate).

Everything seems to work on iOS6 - my code that instantiates the class implementing the protocol is skipped on iOS6 - so it appears I'm good to go.

I was a little surprised not to see an error during app load though; apparently the loader is OK with me implementing a protocol that doesn't exist. Luckily for me!

Is there any Apple documentation that discusses this scenario? Is it safe? Any gotchas I should watch for?

Comment: do you mean a function?

Comment: @Gianmarco No, he means a protocol.

Comment: Right, a protocol. Surprised I couldn't find any prior mention of this scenario, surely it comes up with most iOS & OS X releases?

Comment: Yes it doesn't matter until unless the Class of the object on which a particular method gets called is available. Runtime checks for the method implementation not declaration.

Comment: @nkongara I can see one potential problem with this, though. Information about conformance to a protocol **is** added by the compiler to the code, and it can be queried at runtime. As far as I can tell, Cocoa and Cocoa Touch classes do not use `conformsToProtocol:` to determine if a class conforms to a certain protocol, but if they do, and the run-time protocol information object (one of type `Protocol *`) is not available, this may lead to errors (perhaps a dereferenced `NULL` pointer or something).

Comment: @H2CO3 Ah, yes. For introspection, that makes sense.

Comment: Fair point; in my case I'm doing no introspection, just class instantiation. I note that my app won't create an instance of the class on iOS 6 (understandably).

Comment: Introspection is safe. If you implement a class that conforms to some protocol, the compiler stores a copy of the protocol object in your metadata. There's no reference to the copy of the protocol in the framework, so there's no risk if the framework copy is absent.

Comment: @GregParker I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with that, a bit like implementing a method that is only called by the system for some version upwards.

At worst you can say that you have generated some code that takes up space somewhere (the "disk" if you can call it that on iOS and probably also the RAM) without being used on the older version(s), but that is minimal.

This all requires that the code is compiled with an SDK that includes the protocol in question - if conformance to the protocol is declared by using the `<ProtocolName>` construct and including the corresponding header. But that is kind of a given, since it won't compile otherwise.